# Setting a Google Maps viewport to automatically fit pane for locations of (n) markers of various locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

The approach I took thus far has been:

```
function addMarker( query ) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var afterGeocode = $.Deferred();

    // Geocode 'query' which is the address of a location.
    geocoder.geocode( 
            { address: query }, 
            function( results, status ){

                    if( status === 'OK' ){
                        afterGeocode.resolve( results ); // Activate deferred.
                    }
            }
    );

    afterGeocode.then( function( results ){
        var mOptions = {
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
        }

        // Create and drop in marker.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker( mOptions );
        marker.setAnimation( google.maps.Animation.DROP );      

        var current_bounds = map.getBounds(); // Get current bounds of map
        // use the extend() function of the latlngbounds object
        // to incorporate the location of the marker
        var new_bounds = current_bounds.extend( results[0].geometry.location );
        map.fitBounds( new_bounds ); // fit the map to those bounds
    }); 
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the map inexplicably zooms out by some amount, no matter if the new marker fits within the current viewport or not.

What am I doing wrong?

**ADDENDUM**

I added logs and an additional variable to capture the map bounds *after* the transition was made (new_new_bounds)

```
current_bounds = // Map bounds before anything is done.
    {-112.39575760000002, 33.60691883366427},
    {-112.39295444655761, 33.639099}

new_bounds = // From after the extend
    {-112.39295444655761, 33.60691883366427}, 
    {-112.39575760000002, 33.639099}

new_new_bounds = // From after the fitbounds
    {-112.33942438265382, 33.588697452015374},
    {-112.44928766390382, 33.657309727063996}
```

Comment: What is new_bounds saying it's bounds are after the extend?

Comment: It looks like the change in bounds from (x1,y1),(x2,y2) -> (x2,y1),(x1,y2) is causing a problem. I'm not 100%, but that is where I would start.

Comment: First thing, make sure this isn't a bug by passing current_bounds to fitBounds and seeing if the view moves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, so after much wrangling, it turns out that the problem was a map's bounds are not the same as a map's bounds after `fitBounds()`. What happens (I presume), is Google *takes* the bounds you give it in the `fitBounds()` method, and then pads them. Every time you send the current bounds to `fitBounds()`, You're not going to fit bounds(x,y), you're going to fit bounds(x+m,y+m) where m = the arbitrary margin.

That said, the best approach was this:

```
var current_bounds = map.getBounds();
var marker_pos = marker.getPosition();

if( !current_bounds.contains( marker_pos ) ){

    var new_bounds = current_bounds.extend( marker_pos );
    map.fitBounds( new_bounds );
}
```

So, the map will only fit bounds if a marker placed falls outside the current map bounds. Hope this helps anyone else who hits this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation is that you randomly placed your new marker into the gap of the z-curve. A z-curve recursivley subdivide the map into 4 smaller tiles but that's also the reason why there are gaps between the tiles. A better way would be to use a hilbert curve or a moore curve for map applications. There is a patented search algorithm covering this issue, I think it is called multidimensional range query in quadtrees. You want to look for Nick's hilbert curce quadtree spatial index blog.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time following your answer. I'm just using the standard library provided by the v3 API. The query is simply an address or part of an address.

Comment: dclowd, I've fixed my answer!